# Spotify Web API authorization issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors, spotify

I am relatively new to RectJs and Node and I am trying to fetch some information from Spotify using their API. The Github repo that I got some code from had an HTML file along with the node file for authorization. The authorization and other stuff work fine when I use that HTML to click buttons and trigger calls but when I try to call the authorization endpoint for Spotify using my React server, it gives me this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3054cb711c3c4fc48cff3458cdaddea2&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fcallback&state=J9lrQajWgCnjJy0q' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8888/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

ReactJS server:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Spotify.scss';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class First extends React.Component {  
    handlelogin(){
        axios
        .get('http://localhost:8888/login', {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              }   
        })
        .then()
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }   
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
            <div className="info">   
                <div className="logo"><p>Spotify</p></div>
                <button className="btn" name="login" onClick= {() => this.handlelogin()}> Log-in to Spotify </button>
            </div> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Node Server:

````
var express = require('express'); 
var request = require('request'); 
var cors = require('cors');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


var usersid='';
var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var client_id = '3054cb711c3c4fc48cff3458cdaddea2'; 
var client_secret = 'b43bf5c8fe0040829f0029ac301a5ea7';
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback';

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: '3054cb711c3c4fc48cff3458cdaddea2',
  clientSecret: 'b43bf5c8fe0040829f0029ac301a5ea7',
  redirectUri: 'http://www.localhost:8888'
});

var generateRandomString = function(length) {
  var text = '';
  var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
};

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cors())
   .use(cookieParser());
   
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log('ABCD');
  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  // your application requests authorization
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;
        tokenuse = access_token;
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);

        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
          userid = body.id;
          usersid = body.id;
        });

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } else {
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }
  
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {
  var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
  var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var access_token = body.access_token;
      token = body.access_token;
      res.send({
        'access_token': access_token
      });
    }
  });
});
console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);```
````

Comment: You posted your client secret by the way. I would be careful of sharing that!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't redirect them to Spotify.. ex this:

```
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
```

you should request spotify from your back end and then use the result returned in your application.